# T-SQL Date week day date ranges

Tags: t-sql

I have a simple query to return two columns:

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE 
(
    Product VARCHAR(100)

    )

INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('Hats')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('Hats')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('Hats')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('Hats')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('Shirts')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('Shirts')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('Trousers')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('Trousers')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('Trousers')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('Trousers')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('Trousers')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('Shoes')

SELECT  Product 
        ,COUNT(1) AS Total
        FROM @Test
GROUP BY Product
```

I need to put in my WHERE clause date ranges based on weeks Monday to Friday from different years, finding this one a bit tricky.

i.e
Monday to Friday

2016
06.06.16 – 10.06.16
13.06.16 – 17.06.16

2015
03.08.15 – 07.08.15
10.08.15 – 14.08.15

Comment: please provide your expected output ..?

Comment: Product 03.08.15 – 07.08.15 10.08.15 – 14.08.15 Total
Hats 0           1                                            1                    4
Shirts           1                                         1                    2
Shoes           0                                         1                    1
Trousers           0                                   3                    5

Comment: please add in question  and in your DDL ,there is no dates

Comment: Tried to input it as column headings along the top ie product week ranges, I've tried subqueries for each columns as in (SELECT COUNT(1)FROM @Test WHERE date BETWEEN '20160606' AND '20160613') AS [06.06.16 – 10.06.16]

Comment: Added an Image at top of question

Comment: @TheGameiswar raises a good point.  There are no dates in the `@Test` table.  Without these you have nothing to filter on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate DATETIME = '2016.06.23'

DECLARE @CurrentMonday DATETIME = DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,@CurrentDate), 0) -- 2016.06.20 MONDAY
DECLARE @CurrentFriday DATETIME = DATEADD(dd, 4, @CurrentMonday) -- 2016.06.24 FRIDAY
```

then you can use currentMonday and currentFriday in where clause.

E.g.

```
SELECT
     *
FROM
     YourTable
WHERE
    date >= @CurrentMonday AND
    date <= @CurrentFriday
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE 
(
    Product VARCHAR(100)
    ,DateRange Date

    )

INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('Hats', '20160610')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('Hats','20160612')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('Hats','20150804')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('Hats','20150804')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('Shirts','20150813')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('Shirts','20150825')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('Trousers','20150819')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('Trousers','20150827')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('Trousers','20150607')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('Trousers','20150611')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('Trousers','20150808')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES ('Shoes','20150809')




SELECT
    Product
     ,SUM(CASE WHEN DateRange BETWEEN '20150803' AND '20150807' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '03.08.15 – 07.08.15'
     ,SUM(CASE WHEN DateRange BETWEEN '20150810' AND '20150814' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '10.08.15 – 14.08.15'
     ,SUM(CASE WHEN DateRange BETWEEN '20160606' AND '20160610' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '06.06.16 – 10.06.16'
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN DateRange BETWEEN '20160613' AND '20160617' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '13.06.16 – 17.06.16'
FROM
     @Test
WHERE  Product IN (
        'Hats'
        ,'Shirts'
        ,'Trousers'
        ,'Shoes'
                ) 
GROUP BY Product
 ORDER BY Product ASC
```